# La rature : tous azimuts ?

Tags: sens, informatique, linguistique, style-de-rédaction, conventions

La *rature*, il s'agit de cette « surcharge à l'encre ou au crayon en forme de trait ou de barre, destinée à faire disparaître ce qui était écrit » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rature)) , de ce « trait tracé sur ce qu'on a écrit pour l'annuler » ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rature/66679?q=rature#65939)). Wiktionnaire parle aussi de *trait horizontal* :

> *Voici un exemple : <strike>ce texte est une **rature** sur Wikipédia.</strike>*
>
> [ *Wiktionnaire*, exemple présenté à [*rature*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rature) ]

On sait que lors d'une examen rédigé à la main, on peut vouloir corriger une faute d'orthographe en écrivant de nouveau un même mot, au dessus de la ligne par exemple. Mais voici, je lis un blog, et l'auteur explique longuement son engouement pour un produit ; on termine l'article avec une phrase du type :

> ... et c'est la raison pour laquelle nous avons confiance en
>   <strike>produit X, produit Y,</strike> produit Z.

Il est difficile d'imaginer que ce soit la troisième fois que l'auteur recycle son blog pour vanter un produit différent. Il va sans dire qu'avec l'informatique on peut effacer le texte sans laisser de trace (dans le corps du texte)...

---

Voici un exemple quelque peu différent, littéralement une œuvre d'art de Balzac :

[image]
<sup>[ [*La Femme supérieure*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b530031603/f6.item), Honoré de Balzac, manuscrit autographe (« [Il n'y a pas que les statuaires qui piochent.](http://expositions.bnf.fr/brouillons/grand/21_2.htm) ») ]</sup>

On y trouve *au moins* cinq manières différentes de raturer en couverture ; on a des ratures verticales sur des lettres individuelles, des ratures qui ressemblent à des *e* en lettres attachées etc. Parfois on raye avec davantage de force ou avec je ne sais quoi de différent techniquement (comme ce mot dont la rature ressort dans la partie droite de l'image). On n'*annule* pas tout de la même manière, si du tout.

---

Dans un contexte complètement différent, normatif, on peut voir la [rature](http://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/rature.php) comme un « ajout négatif » à un texte préétabli, et on peut imaginer des manières de raturer nuisant au [décompte](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/N-3?langCont=fr#se:46), des mots rayés, que l'on prescrit :

> Il n'y a ni surcharge ni interligne ni addition dans le corps de
>   l'acte et les mots et les chiffres surchargés, interlignés ou ajoutés
>   sont nuls. Les blancs nécessités par l'utilisation des procédés de
>   reproduction sont barrés. Le nombre de blancs barrés, celui des mots
>   et des nombres rayés sont mentionnés à la fin de l'acte. Cette mention
>   est paraphée par le notaire et les autres signataires de l'acte.
>
> [ *Décret n°71-941 du 26 novembre 1971 relatif aux actes établis par les notaires*, [art. 13](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000511476&fastPos=1&fastReqId=1396024033&categorieLien=cid&oldAction=rechTexte#LEGIARTI000006490100) (France) ]

Évidemment si on n'ajoute pas la mention tel qu'indiqué, ou qu'on fait un ajout discret de rature postérieur à la signature et qu'on oubliera par la suite de reproduire sur les copies d'actes, la manière de rayer un mot aura alors peu d'importance, et les conséquences pourront être désastreuses ([Cassation](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichJuriJudi.do?idTexte=JURITEXT000030354842) ; plus didactique : [déontologie](http://citoyens.soquij.qc.ca/php/decision.php?ID=1EB98E0633240E3EBC0A4975E46CA4BD&page=1)). En d'autres termes dans certains cas la rature change le sens autant sinon davantage qu'elle ne corrige une erreur.

---

- **La rature manuscrite et la rature *numérique* sont-elles la même rature** ; quel est le sens de la rature quand on peut simplement effacer le texte avec l'éditeur etc. (informatique) ; quel est le sens de la rature du blogueur mentionné en introduction, est-ce même une rature, qu'est-ce donc ; la rature n'a-t-elle qu'une seule fonction et qu'un seul objet ?
- **Y a-t-il un usage ou une convention quant à la manière de raturer à la main en français** ; est-il naturel et significatif de faire un trait le plus horizontal possible ; y a-t-il un classement des types de ratures ; certains types de ratures sont-elles immédiatement associées à des auteurs particuliers ?
- **La rature enlève-t-elle ou ajoute-t-elle au [signifié](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/signifi%C3%A9/72711?q=signifi%C3%A9#71902)** ; un type de rature particulier change-t-il différemment le signifié d'un autre, en d'autres mots chaque type de rature constitue-t-il un signe différent, et si oui à quelle(s) condition(s) ou dans quel contexte ?

Answer (score 2):

Concernant le blog, il y a deux possibilités :

1. L'auteur a édité 2 fois son article. Il rature le mot "produit X" pour que les personnes qui ont déjà lu l'article puissent facilement identifier ce que l'auteur a modifié.
2. L'auteur fait semblant de se tromper. Cela peut arriver pour montrer qu'on s'emporte en écrivant (par colère ou hâte par exemple), mais que ce n'est pas politiquement correct. Par exemple, on pourra écrire "Pierre est <strike>un vrai con</strike> quelqu'un que je n'apprécie pas beaucoup !". C'est donc une figure de style humoristique.

---

Faire une rature, c'est corriger une faute. En général, on fait une rayure horizontale pour barrer un mot entier.
Si on met un "s" en trop sur un mot (ou un accent en trop), la rayure horizontale ne se verra pas assez, donc si un professeur veut montrer la faute, il va plutôt faire une croix (un "x"), car on distingue toujours le "s" derrière la croix. Si c'est un élève qui corrige sa faute en écrivant, il va souvent masquer le "s" en raturant complètement la lettre, mais c'est très lourd graphiquement, donc considéré comme pas propre.
Aussi, beaucoup de personnes, en faisant un "x", font en fait un "e" (ou la lettre "alpha"), car ne relèvent pas le stylo entre les deux barres du "x", cela représente donc la même chose.
Après, je pense que chacun est libre de faire la rature qu'il souhaite suivant le contexte.

---

Je pense avoir répondu à la 3ème question juste au dessus.
Je rajouterais peut-être la rature multiple dans le cadre d'une correction faite par une autre personne, si on veut signifier que c'est une grosse faute. Donc au lieu de faire une rature horizontale, on va en faire plusieurs successives (avec pourquoi pas le commentaire "NON !!!" à coté), signe que la faute provoque de l'énervement (plus ou moins intense).

Comment: Merci ! Mais qu'en est-il de la possibilité que l'auteur du blog ait X, Y et Z dès le départ, et qu'il retranche les produits pour lesquels il n'a plus confiance. D'accord on aurait peut-être la coord. _et_ avant le dernier terme, mais qui sait... Bon rappel sur des considérations pratiques. Pensez-vous que l'auteur qui fait semblant de se tromper s'applique aussi à l'écriture à la main ; avez-vous un commentaire sur l'adéquation entre la rature manuscrite et numérique (_strikethrough_). Existe-t-il d'autres fautes que des fautes orthographiques ?

Comment: @exilanceéglisée L'utilisation de "," implique qu'avant correction on indiquait faire confiance en X, Y, et Z, mais comme vous soulignez, il manquerait la coordination "et"... Le plus probable est donc que l'auteur veut explicitement dire qu'il n'a pas confiance en X et Y, alors que s'il ne parle que du produit Z, on pourrait croire qu'il a oublié de parler de X et Y...

Comment: @exilanceéglisée Concernant le fait de faire semblant de se tromper, je ne vois pas de contre-indication à l'utilisation manuscrite, mais la "blague" est moins évidente que sur ordinateur... Sur ordinateur il est plus facile de corriger les fautes avant d'envoyer un mail. A l'écrit, les ratures "classiques" sont donc beaucoup plus fréquentes si on écrit rapidement... Concernant les autres fautes raturées, il peut aussi y avoir des fautes de vocabulaire, si l'auteur confond plusieurs termes techniques par exemple. Il est difficile de raturer une faute de grammaire (peut-être moins excusable ?)